# Group and count multiple fields at once

Tags: sql, filter, lucene, search-engine, data-warehouse

Is it possible to merge these queries so the search criteria is executed only once?

```
SELECT category, count(*)
FROM   ads
WHERE  [search criteria]
GROUP BY category

SELECT state, count(*)
FROM   ads
WHERE  [search criteria]
GROUP BY state

SELECT price_range, count(*)
FROM   ads
WHERE  [search criteria]
GROUP BY price_range

...

Plus about 10 more COUNTS
```

My aim is to create a filter similar to that is used in [this website](http://www.zap.com.br/imoveis/brasil/?q=sao%20paulo).

I'm thinking about using some kind of search engine (eg. Lucene) instead of relational database. New ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eduardo,
Are you allowed to use a stored procedure?  If so, you can execute the common part first.

```
SELECT ... 
FROM   ads WHERE  [search criteria]
```

Then you can do your multiple queries on the smaller table.  You can also store the results and return the whole thing as one table with three columns:

1. type (category, state, price range, etc)
2. name (actually category/state/etc value)
3. count

Comment: Hi Jeanne. If I do so I will execute search criteria multiple times inside the stored procedure.

Comment: Not if you only call the stored procedure once.  The stored procedure executes the search criteria once and stores the results in a "temporary table" (more like a temporary variable.)  The other queries, run against the temporary set of data not by repeatedly executing the where clause.

Comment: Note that if you are able to use analytic functions, that is better.  I didn't want to presume your database.

Comment: I had misunderstood. Should I index that temp table?

Comment: No need to index it.  The temp table only exists for the scope of the stored procedure.  It only contains the results that passed your where clause so you are past the point of indexing.  If your where clause is going to be the same across users/calls to this query (and your database supports them), you might want to consider materialized views instead.

Comment: Hi Jeanne. I believe I found a solution very close to yours. I create a key-value table and store: 1. object type (ad) 2. key(category, state, price range, etc) 3. value (actually category, state, etc value). Count is done by SELECT COUNT(...) . This way I can store anything and combine like a faceted search.

Answer (score 3):

What's the DBMS? In Oracle you can do that with analytic functions:

```
SELECT category, state, price_range,
       COUNT( 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY category ) AS category_count,
       COUNT( 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY state) AS state_count,
       COUNT( 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY price_range ) AS price_count
  FROM ads
```

Comment: Very nice feature. Unfortunately it's MySQL.

Comment: You probably have to go with a temp table than.

Answer (score 1):

If your use case includes full-text search in addition to the queries you listed, [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) might be worth looking at. In incorporates faceted search over structured and text data, and can do the kinds of counts you want reasonably efficiently. But it depends in part on how much data you have, and what your use cases are.

Comment: +1 I've been searching for Lucene which Solr is based on but haven't found how to do those counts without iterating over results. I've been searching for other no-sql solutions as well.

Comment: Solr will do the counting for you; just specify which categories should be included in the results. You don't access Lucene directly when using Solr, because Solr wraps that for you. Perhaps I am mis-understanding your request: can you say more?

Answer (score 0):

you can do by using nested query and some tricks ;)

```
  select category,countCategory,state,countState,price_range,countPrice_range from 
    (SELECT 1 pcol,category, count(*) countCategory
    FROM   ads
    WHERE  [search criteria]
    GROUP BY category) 
    a
    inner  join
    (
    SELECT 1 pcol,state, count(*) countState
    FROM   ads
    WHERE  [search criteria]
    GuROUP BY state
    ) b
    on a.pcol=b.pcol
    inner join
    (SELECT 1 pcol,price_range, count(*) countPrice_range
    FROM   ads
    WHERE  [search criteria]
    GROUP BY price_range)
    )
    on a.pcol=b.pcol
```